# Search results not printing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've built a search bar into my application.html.erb header that allows my visitors to search "Users" on my site, and upon clicking the 'submit' button to show search results, found results don't seem to print on my page (it's merely blank).

I've created index.html.erb under my users folder, as well as _user.html.erb, so I'm not sure why this is happening (as I understand it, _user.html.erb is necessary to display found/rendered results)?

Is there a line of code I should be placing in _user.html.erb?

Here's what's in my **index.html.erb**:

```
<% if @user.present? %>
  <%= render @user %>
<% else %>
  <p>There are no posts containing the term(s) <%= params[:search] %>.</p>
<% end %>
```

Incase you need my other files:

**users_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @user = User.all
  if params[:search]
    @user = User.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @user = User.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
def self.search(search)
  where("firstname LIKE ?", "%#{search}%") 
  where("lastname LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

Comment: Can you please include `_user.html.erb`?

Comment: yes, you have to add something like this in your `_user.html.erb`,  `<%= user.name %>` since @user is an instance of User model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### View

It's not usually done to pass `params` back to the view - mainly I think because it changes for each request, and it might end up being different to what you expect. You probably want to copy this to an instance variable in the controller.

```
<% if @users.present? %>
  <%= render @users %>
<% else %>
  <p>There are no posts containing the term(s) <%= @search %>.</p>
<% end %>
```

### Partial

**_user.html.erb**

```
<%= user.firstname %> <%= user.lastname%>
```

### Controller

1. Scrap `@user = User.all`, it doesn't do anything.
2. You're returning more than one user; your variable should be called `@users` for readability.
3. Scrap `.all` in the `else` clause, it's not necessary.

It should be:

```
def index
  @search = params[:search]
  if @search
    @users = User.search(@search).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @users = User.order('created_at DESC')
  end
end
```

### Model

`where("firstname LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")` is getting ignored. It runs it, but throws the result away and returns only the result of the next line. You want:

```
def self.search(search)
  where("firstname LIKE :p OR lastname LIKE :p", p: "%#{search}%")
end
```

---

## Multi field search

- Search multiple fields for multiple tokens out of a single parameter

You are a **masochist** if you want to try this. But it is possible, and I have done it before.

*Note: this is written for SQL Server 2008, as that's what my company was using at the time. Some SQL functions - particularly `IsNull` and `LIKE` - may be different depending on what you're using.*

```
class User
  scope :search, ->(value) do
    # This allows tokens containing A-z, 0-9, _, and %. Anything else is treated
    # as a delimiter.
    multi_field_search(%w[firstname lastname], value.split(/[^\w%]/))
  end

  # This scope is generic, and reusable for any combination of string fields in
  # any model.
  scope :multi_field_search, ->(fields, values) do
    # You're looking in these fields...
    fields_clause = fields.select(&:present?).map do |field|
      "IsNull(#{field}, '')"
    end.join(" + ' ' + ")

    # ... for these values...
    values_clause = sanitize_conditions(values.select(&:present?).map do |value|
      "combo_view.combination LIKE '%#{value}%'"
    end.join(' AND '))

    # ... and you do it by constructing a query to join the fields together, and
    # searching for each token of the search parameter individually.
    joins(<<-SQL).where(values_clause)
      INNER JOIN (
        SELECT *, #{fields_clause} AS combination
        FROM #{table_name}
      ) AS combo_view ON #{table_name}.#{primary_key} = combo_view.#{primary_key}
    SQL
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: This works like a charm - thank you! What if I type a first and last name into my search field though? e.g. Searching "Brittany" pulls up a first name and lastname result, but searching "Brittany Miller" brings up no results.

Comment: Oooh, I had fun with that one not too long ago. It was ***nasty***. I'll throw in an update above.

Comment: Thank you so much - and strange, searching multiple fields seems like it would be an easy/common task?! No? My rails app is sitting on Sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting no results on your `search` method, that's why you don't see any results after. Change your `where` statements, since it's creating and AND query and you are probably looking for an OR. Please try something like:

```
def self.search(search)
    where("firstname LIKE ? OR lastname LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
end
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Changed to your suggestion, and still no results are printed :/